# Why dont my POST requests update the .json or .js files being served?

Tags: javascript, rest, express, graphql, crud

I know i'm missing something simple here. Go easy on me.

I have a graphQL back end that serves the following:

```
const arr = [ { id: 1, foo: 'foo' }, { id: 2, foo: 'bar' }]
```

then i make a graphql mutation request via buildSchema()

```
type Mutation {
        updateFooValue(id: Int!, foo: String!): MySchema
}
```

in my rootResolver I've configured:

```
var root = {
    getFooQuery: getFooFunc,
    getFoosQuery: getFoosFunction,
    updateFooValue: updateFooFunc,
};
```

Then i have that updateFooFunc as:

```
var updateFooFunc = function ({ id, foo }) {
    arr.map(each => {
        if (each.id === id) {
            each.foo = foo;
            return each;
        }
    });
    return arr.filter(each => each.id === id)[0];
}
```

**This all actually works fine** in the localhost / graphiql UI, but when i check the array it hasn't updated.

Similar problem yesterday using a fetch / REST post request. The localhost/JSON and immediate fetch reqs were fine but the original .json file stayed the same. Obviously means restarting the server = you lose any new accounts/new chat msgs or whatever - so *clearly* not the right way to do this.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things to keep in mind here.

When you start your server, variables like `arr` are kept in memory only as long as the server is running. Changes to the variables' values will only change what's in memory -- it won't update what's in your actual code. When your stop your server, the variable values are released from memory. If the server is started again, those variables will once again have whatever initial value you gave them.

Generally, if you want to **persist** your data, you need to write it to and read it from a database or some other data store (like Redis). You can also read/write files directly (see [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp) for a basic overview of how to do that in node).

As an aside, it's also important to keep in mind that array methods like `filter` and `map` do not mutate the original value of the array they are called on.

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array.map(item => item * 2)
console.log(array) // still shows [1, 2, 3, 4]
array.filter(item => item > 3)
console.log(array) // still shows [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you want the original value to change, you need to do something like this:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4] // use let since our value will not be *constant*
array = array.map(item => item * 2)
console.log(array) // now shows [2, 4, 6, 8]
array.filter(item => item > 3)
console.log(array) // now shows [4, 6, 8]
```

You can also chain your methods like this

```
array = array.map(item => item * 2).filter(item => item > 3)
```

Putting it all together, if you want your resolver to just read and write from a file, it would look something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const updateFooFunc = ({ id, foo }) => {
  // assuming foo.json exists
  const valueFromFile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./foo.json'))
  const newValue = valueFromFile.map(each => {
    if (each.id === id) each.foo = foo
    return each
  })
  fs.writeFileSync(JSON.stringify('./foo.json', newValue))
  // "find" is a little better than "filter" for what you're doing
  return newValue.find(each => each.id === id) 
}
```

Comment: As an additional aside, using the root value is a very limited way to pass in resolvers. As you continue exploring GraphQL, I would highly suggest eventually using `graphql-tools` and building your schema using `makeExecutableSchema` instead.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRearden - i thought there was something else i was supposed to pull in that i just overlooked before. But you're quite right. If you want the static js/json file updated, you need to dabble with the fs/writeFile/Node'y stuff. Have written something along those lines and it's now performing well. Thank you!